# Can oncogenesis happen without apoptosis pathway being affected?

Tags: cancer, apoptosis

Has there ever been incidences of one or more cancerous cells having all it's cell-death pathways and apoptosis mechanisms intact and functional?

Comment: Are any apoptosis mechanisms in a cell that are not functioning or suppressed or damaged a typical sign of a cancerous cell?

Comment: Could something be used to cause a mutation in a cancer cell that is 'noticeable' to the immune system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually the cell death mechanisms are overridden and therefore oncogenesis. The pathway components themselves are not mutated. One classical case I can cite is that of Ras-oncogene. See this [article](http://cancerres.aacrjournals.org/content/72/10/2457.long) for details. Usually the survival/growth signals (MAP-kinase) are activated with simultaneous inactivation of apoptotic regulators (Akt-pathway). A mutation of MAP-kinase component ERK can also cause cancer but apoptosis is nonetheless supressed because of the interconnections of these tow pathways in the gene regulatory network.

Whereas in the case of tumor suppressors, the cause of cancer is genomic instability and failure to initiate apoptosis.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty unlikely, since one of the most important steps for cancer cells is to shut off apoptosis and proteins which control it (like p53, BCL2 and so on). Cancer cells (especially when they are genetically unstable) acquire so much mutations and misregulations, that these would otherwise trigger apoptosis which would result in the removal of the cell.

This can look like the following (figure taken from [here](http://www.molecular-cancer.com/content/9/1/144/figure/F3)), when you compare normal and cancer cell:

[image]

Comment: quite a complete figure.. i like it..

Comment: Thanks. It is a slightly different perspective to your figure.

Comment: Does a pre-cancerous cell shut off apoptosis and the proteins that control it before it becomes a cancer cell or is it the case a cancer cell shuts off apoptosis mechanisms after it is already cancerous?

Comment: Usually apoptosis is affected in a later stage of oncogenesis. However, in case of DNA damage induced oncogenesis, there is a failure to initiate apoptosis when the DNA is damaged and not repaired. In this case the signal has not yet reached the apoptotic pathway. This ensues genomic instability which may further lead to uncontrolled growth i.e cancer (as you can imagine, to grow and multiply maximally is the first instinct of any lifeform)

Comment: Is there some way to detect if a cells apoptosis mechanisms have been shut down or made to malfunction? If so could this be a way to detect if a cell is cancerous?

Comment: @user128932 You could do a genome analysis and search for inactivating mutations. Since there is more than one way to activated apoptosis, this usually happens only in cells which have already gone down the cancer path.

Comment: Is there a less involved method then genome analysis to see if a cell has had its apoptosis mechanisms 'turned off'? If cancer cells are immortal-like can they withstand many types of viruses or harmful bacteria or phagocytes?

Comment: If a cell sample has only cells with no apoptosis mechanisms but it has not been determined if they are cancerous ; if some process can induce cellular growth that would not occur if the cells were not cancerous would this show this cell culture has no apoptosis mechanisms?

Comment: Can a cell with no apoptosis mechanism spontaneously reproduce in conditions it shouldn't be able?

Comment: @user128932 Sorry, but I don't understand your last question. You want to know if cells without apoptosis can divide?

Comment: My question on Nov 2 at 3:48 ; yes , can a cell without any apoptosis mechanisms divide , given it is in a 'situation'(possibly artificially induced) were it shouldn't be able to divide?

Comment: Again, cancer cells are an example. Disabled apoptosis is not uncommon, this mechanism is used to evade apoptosis.

Comment: If a cell has a lot of mutations yet it can still function would this make any apoptosis mechanism not 'work'?

Comment: This depends on the specific mutation itself.

Comment: So some types of mutated cells can still have all its apoptosis mechanisms working? What kind of mutation can cause an apoptosis mechanism to malfunction?

Comment: @201044 Can you please stop asking questions in the comments and open a new question instead?

Comment: @201044 First: Perpetual questions in the comments are not liked. Then: You ask questions, so you need to decide if you want to know more or not. I am not going to open a question for this.

Comment: I don't repeat the same question over and over again; that would be a perpetual question. Why argue about 'meta-biology' stack exchange issues  or other syntax or 'administrative' issues when I have asked relevant questions even in the comments. If this bother's you people just ignore it. Don't make a separate issue out of it.

Comment: The original question was ; have there been  any examples of active cancer cells with an apoptosis mechanism that is functioning?